# SASS/SCSS variable not working with CSS variable assignment

Tags: css, sass

I have the following SCSS code:

```scss
@mixin foo($bar: 42) {
    --xyzzy: $bar;
}
bar {
    @include foo;
}
```

I would expect that I get CSS variable `--xyzzy` set to `42` on all `bar` elements. Instead of this, I get CSS stating `bar { --xyzzy: $bar; }`. The variable was not interpreted. I would need to use `#{…}` syntax instead to get the variable set.

Is this a feature of the SCSS/SASS? A bug? Can I get the interpretation working without enclosing the variable name in `#{…}`?

Actual result:

```css
bar {
  --xyzzy: $bar;
}
```

Expected:

```css
bar {
  --xyzzy: 42;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not a bug, it's how the Sass compiler works regarding CSS custom properties, known as CSS variables. The syntax `#{…}` is called [interpolation](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/interpolation), and it is the only way to inject dynamic values into a custom property. Here is a quote from the [doc](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/style-rules/declarations#custom-properties):

> CSS custom properties, also known as CSS variables, have an unusual declaration syntax: they allow almost any text at all in their declaration values. What’s more, those values are accessible to JavaScript, so any value might potentially be relevant to the user. This includes values that would normally be parsed as SassScript.

> Because of this, Sass parses custom property declarations differently than other property declarations. All tokens, including those that look like SassScript, are passed through to CSS as-is. The only exception is `interpolation`, which is the only way to inject dynamic values into a custom property.

That's the reason why you have that behavior, and only doing so works:

```scss
@mixin foo($bar: 42) {
   --xyzzy: $bar;    // does not work
   --xyzzy: #{$bar}; // works
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I destroyed my brain for 2 hours trying to understand why it dosent work.

```
  --primary-color: #{map.get($dark-theme-app-var, primary-color)};
  --primary-color: map.get($dark-theme-app-var, primary-color);
```

and chatGpt did not catch that :).
Thank you.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).