# Variables are not compiled when scss is compiled

Tags: .net, sass

Variables are not compiled when scss is compiled

```scss
$gos-colors-aqua: #7FDBFF;
:r {

    --gos-colors-aqua: $gos-colors-aqua;
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YsUjv.png)

Comment: I found that he couldn't compile with '--', and would simply ignore it

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SASS/SCSS variable not working with CSS variable assignment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73079963/sass-scss-variable-not-working-with-css-variable-assignment)

Comment: I have found that when I use SASS I use SASS variables. When I use CSS I use CSS variables. No need to mix them

Answer (score 0):

SASS Compiler doesn't allow using sass variable directly in front of CSS variable,
So, to do this you should define '--' prefix as a variable and put it before CSS variable like the code below:

SASS:

```
$gos-colors-aqua: #7FDBFF
$prefix: --
:r
  #{$prefix}gos-colors-aqua: $gos-colors-aqua
```

Or in SCSS:

```
$gos-colors-aqua: #7FDBFF;
$prefix: --;
:r{
    #{$prefix}gos-colors-aqua: $gos-colors-aqua;
}
```

Or in another standard way, you can put your sass variable in #{}:

```
$gos-colors-aqua: #7FDBFF;
:r{
    --gos-colors-aqua: #{$gos-colors-aqua};
}
```

CSS result:

```
:r {
  --gos-colors-aqua: #7FDBFF;
}
```

Comment: The solution is to encode the -- transformation and then compile the transformation back